# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pyqt, ascii, encode

Ι've tried all the solution that I could find, but nothing seems to work:

```
teext = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
```

I'm writing in greek by the way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Clearly, `self.tableWidget.item().text()` returns Unicode, and you need to use the `decode` method instead:

```
self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text().encode('utf8')
```

You really want to review the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to fully appreciate the difference between a unicode object and it's byte encoding.

Another excellent article is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), by Joel Spolsky (one of the people behind Stack Overflow).

Comment: Well, i do not get errors any more, but when I'm writing teext to an .xls file, when I open the .xls file it shows nothing...

Comment: Read the articles I included in my answer; you'll need to find out what encoding you need to use.

Comment: teext = unicode(self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text()) seems to solve the problem... Anyway, thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 2):

Try put following code in the beginning
It's fixed my problem perfectly

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
teext = self.tableWidget.item(row, col).text().decode('utf-8')
```

Replace 'utf-8' with encoding of your text