# Weird python encoding error in Vim with make

Tags: python, vim, encoding, makefile

I have file `test.py` with content:

```
print u'\u0410'
```

and `Makefile`:

```
test:
    python test.py
```

When I write in Vim `:!python test.py` I get

```
А

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But when I write `:make test` I get

```
python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print u'\u0410'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0410' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
make: *** [test] Error 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

`make test` in terminal is ok.

Anyone have any ideas why it is could be so? Could you reproduce? Or is it only something with my setup?

Comment: I can reproduce it. I don't know why this is happening. But the reason it works differently in the shell is `:make test` is calling make through vim's internal commands. (So vim could be screwing something up). This is different from `:!make test` which runs make in the shell. (Notice the `!`). Seems to be the same problem as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923663/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-in-position-0-ordinal

Comment: Using `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python test.py` in the makefile fixes the problem. This was taken from the answer in the previously linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
print u'\u0410'
```

to:

```
print u'\u0410'.encode('utf-8')
```

What's happening here is that vim adds `2>&1 | tee` (from the `shellpipe` setting) after `make` (which is set from the `makeprg` setting). So your `test.py` script is in effect being redirected. Try running `$ test.py > /tmp/foo` and you'll get the same error. Solution: encode your output to a reasonable encoding, like `utf-8`.